# vuejs: ref tag in dom element not work when use with object attribute

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, ref

With this code:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue"

const input1 = ref(null)

const group = {
  input2: ref(null),
  input3: ref(null),
}

function main() {
  console.log("input1", input1?.value?.value)
  console.log("input1", group.input3?.value?.value)
  console.log("input3", group.input3?.value?.value)

  document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value = `
    input1: ${input1?.value?.value}
    input2: ${group.input2?.value?.value}
    input3: ${group.input3?.value?.value}
  `.trim()
}
</script>

<template>
  <input ref="input1" type="text" value="1" />
  <input ref="group.input2" type="text" value="2" />
  <input ref="group.input3" type="text" value="3" />

  <button @click="main">click</button>

  <p>
    <textarea cols="30" rows="6"></textarea>
  </p>
</template>
```

when you do `click`, you get `input1` in `input1.value`, but yo don't get `input2` and `input3` in `group.input2.value` and `group.input3.value`, you get null instead.

Why `input1.value` works but `group.input2.value` and `group.input3.value` are always null?

How can I defined a one single object with one attribute for each input?
What I am really want to achieve is a single object that represent all inputs in a form.

Comment: you should use v-model instead of ref in your input elements

Comment: @c.m.  I need ref because of I need get the real dom element not just its value (in my example I only use the value for simplicity, but in the real case I am going to manipulate the dom element)